# Selecting XML node together will all children

Tags: xml, children, nodes, selectall

I want to select a node together with all child nodes from an XML document that I have loaded. What method whould I use to get, for example below, `<item2>` and all child nodes (child 2.1,2.2,2.3)?

```
<xmldoc>
  <item1>
    <child1.1>
    <child1.2>
    <child1.3>
  </item1>
  <item2>
    <child2.1>
    <child2.2>
    <child2.3>
  </item2>
</xmldoc>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you need (as mentioned in question) to *select* `item2` **and** all its child nodes, XPath expression will be

```
xmldoc/item2 | xmldoc/item2/*
```

And if you need all descendants (e.g. for more complicated structure)

```
xmldoc/item2/descendant-or-self::*
```

Comment: Thanks! I needed to select item2 and children as stated.

Answer (score 0):

The xpath expression should be /xmldoc/item2/*
Otherwise you should specify in what language...